# JWT and Uploading Images

Tags: authentication, jwt

I am wondering about some strategies regarding a particular issue I am facing. Let's imagine that there's an authentication system implemented using JWT.

Users sign-in, they get a token which has the following payload:

```
{ username: 'John', email: 'john@example.com', photo: null }
```

(they payload is generated based on a database query, say `SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = 1`)

When (and only when) the user is logged in, they can upload an image. The image gets stored somewhere, the user entry is updated in the database.

The problem I am facing is that now they need to login and log-back in again to see the profile photo updated since the profile information is displayed based on the token payload which will still not contain the `photo`. The next time they login of course it'll be updated:

```
{ username: 'John', email: 'john@example.com', photo: 'john-img.jpg' }
```

So the question is - how to handle the situation when the profile data is show from a token and there's a file upload procedure and I wish to display the image?

I know that the client shouldn't (and cannot) update the token, because that will automatically cause the token to be invalidated.

Are there any strategies out there that are acceptable? Should I rethink the logic of doing file uploads while logged in? Should this not be tied to a JWT? Should the profile page not be built up from the token?

Answer (score 0):

@Tamas you should never keep user photo in JWT Token, as this is not the ideal or recommended way, instead you can keep this in User(database) table and always update user data on profile update,

But if they really want to go with this option only? you can still do this by keeping user image info in localstorage, by the time user login and logout you can get image info from localstorage.

hope this could help.

Comment: Thanks @Chetan Prakash. Why is it a bad idea to keep the image name in the JWT? I was also thinking of the local storage option, this involves some additional logic but I guess I could live with that. :)